# How to extract the Signature from an x509 Certificate

Tags: python, openssl, x509, pyopenssl

I am trying to extract the signature from a loaded x509 Certificate. I have everything else extracted (issuer, subject, PEM, SignatureAlgorithm, etc). I have searched for this, but have come up short. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

certobj = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, cert)

issuer = certobj.get_issuer()
subject = certobj.get_subject()

certDetails = {
    "SerialNumber": certobj.get_serial_number(),
    "Signature": None,  # <-- This is what I am trying to get!
    "SignatureAlgorithm": certobj.get_signature_algorithm(),
    "CertificatePEM": crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certobj),
    "SubjectPublicKeyPEM": crypto.dump_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certobj.get_pubkey()),
    "Version": certobj.get_version()
}
```

Comment: are you looking for the public key? that is what actually allows you to send a trusted message to the CA: [`certobj.get_pubkey()`](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.X509.get_pubkey)

Comment: @Aaron No. I have the public key stored in `certDetails.SubjectPublicKeyPEM`. I am looking for the signature value itself.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while since the question was asked but for anyone else who needs, there are two options,

```
signing_algo = cert_obj.signature_hash_algorithm.name
```

or

```
signing_algo = cert_obj.signature_algorithm_oid._name
```

cert_obj is instance of cryptography.x509.Certificate

Answer (score -1):

A little roundabout but I converted the certificate to a cryptography Certificate object to access the signature:

cryptCert = cert.to_cryptography()

print hexlify(cryptCert.signature)